# Django: Thread causing InMemoryUploadedFile to prematurely close?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, file-io

Good day,

I have a problem where a CSV file, sent to a View and later passed into a new thread for processing, sometimes closes prematurely and I can't figure out why. The behaviour is intermittent and only started happening after I switched to using a new thread to process the file.

This is the original way I was processing the file and it worked, but for large files it caused time-out issues on the client:

```python
class LoadCSVFile(APIView):
    permission_class = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request):
        file = request.FILES['file']
        data_set = file.read().decode('utf-8')
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)

        for row_data in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
            print('row_data:', row_data)

        return Response({ 'message': 'File received and is currently processing.', 'status_code': status.HTTP_200_OK }, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

So I now process the file in a new thread like so:

```python
class LoadCSVFile(APIView):
    permission_class = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request):
        request_handler = RequestHandler(request)
        csv_handler = CSVHandler(request.FILES['file'])

        # Fire and forget the file processing.
        t = threading.Thread(target=request_handler.resolve, kwargs={ 'csv_handler': csv_handler })
        t.start()
        return Response({ 'message': 'File received and is currently processing.', 'status_code': status.HTTP_200_OK }, status.HTTP_200_OK)


class RequestHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, request : Request):
        self.request = request

    def resolve(self, **kwargs):
        csv_handler = kwargs['csv_handler']

        try:
            print('Processing file...')
            csv_handler.process_file()
        except Exception as e:
            print('process_file level error:', e)


class CSVHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def get_reader(self):
        # Error is raised at the following line: "I/O operation on closed file."
        data_set = self.file.read().decode('utf-8')
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        return csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    def process_file(self, **kwargs):
        for row_data in self.get_reader():
            print('row_data:', row_data)
```

For a while it was great, but then I started to notice occasional I/O errors.

- This happens with large (5000 lines) and small (2 lines) files.
- I can go 50 uploads without seeing the error, then it will happen 2 or 3 times in a row. Or anywhere in between.
- Both the request is saved in the RequestHandler and the file is saved in CSVHandler before the thread is initiated and I don't know how else to keep the InMemoryUploadedFile alive until I need it (`csv_handler.get_reader()`).

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: first of, why is the data stored in csv, can you not use alternatives like Mongodb?

Comment: Alternatively, you might need to include  a Queue with your thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the main thread returning from the POST request prior to the CSV file being opened by `csv_handler.get_reader()`. I'm still not sure how the file gets lost while the `RequestHandler` and `CSVHandler` have references on the `request` and `file` objects. Maybe it's a Django thing.

I fixed it by moving the reader logic up into the `CSVHandler` constructor and using a lock to prevent the race condition.

```python
class CSVHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        with self.lock:
            self.file = file
            data_set = self.file.read().decode('utf-8')
            io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
            self.reader = csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    def process_file(self, **kwargs):
        for row_data in self.reader:
            print('row_data:', row_data)
```